# Can I use scrapy to split a webpage's content when I hit a certain tag?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm attempting to scrape the data from a webpage using scrapy that looks like so:

```
<h3 id="greatCleave">Great Cleave [General]</h3>

<h5>Prerequisites</h5>
<p>
    Str 13, <a href="#cleave">Cleave</a>, <a href="#powerAttack">Power Attack</a>, base attack bonus +4.
</p>

<h5>Benefit</h5>
<p>
    This feat works like <a href="#cleave">Cleave</a>, except that there is no limit to the number of times you can use it per round.
</p>

<h5>Special</h5>
<p>
    A <a href="/srd/classes/fighter.htm">fighter</a> may select Great Cleave as one of his fighter bonus feats.
</p>



<h3 id="greatFortitude">Great Fortitude [General]</h3>

<h5>Benefit</h5>
<p>
    You get a +2 bonus on all <a href="/srd/combat/combatStatistics.htm#fortitude">Fortitude saving throws</a>.
</p>



<h3 id="greaterSpellFocus">Greater Spell Focus [General]</h3>
<p>
    Choose a school of magic to which you already have applied the <a href="#spellFocus">Spell Focus</a> feat.
</p>

<h5>Benefit</h5>
<p>
    Add +1 to the Difficulty Class for all <a href="/srd/combat/combatStatistics.htm#savingThrows">saving throws</a> against spells from the school of magic you select. This bonus stacks with the bonus from <a href="#spellFocus">Spell Focus</a>.
</p>

<h5>Special</h5>
<p>
    You can gain this feat multiple times. Its effects do not stack. Each time you take the feat, it applies to a new school of magic to which you already have applied the <a href="#spellFocus">Spell Focus</a> feat.
</p>


etc...
```

The general pattern is a h3 heading, and then 1 to 4 h5 subheadings and description paragraphs. I'd like to split these into separate items, where the h3 is the name and h5s are various attributes. Right now, the code I have in my scrapy parser to do so looks like this:

```
def parse(self,response):
    for feat in response.xpath('//h3'):
        item = FeatItem()
        item['name'] = feat.xpath(".//text()").extract_first()

        headerlist= feat.xpath("./following-sibling::h5/text()").extract()
        paralist= feat.xpath("./following-sibling::p/text()").extract()
```

This gives me what I want, sort of. I end up with all of the following h5 data or p data, respectively, not just the ones that are following until I hit the next h3. Since the amount of data in between h3 tags varies, I'd like to split the site into portions at the h3 tags so I can examine each chunk individually. Is this possible?